# Overriding a single configuration in a Postgres Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to override a single item in the `Postgres` configuration of the official `Docker` `Postgres` image. Namely, I want to override the `log_statement` property and set it to `all`.

Tried it with:

```
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres postgres -c 'log_statement=all'
```

After enter the docker container and execute:

```
cat /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf | grep log_statement
```

is still get the default value which is `none`.

but without success.

There are a few answers/questions regarding `Postgres` `Docker` configuration but they suggest replacing the complete `postgresql.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/config-setting.html):

> Command-line options override any conflicting settings in postgresql.conf. Note that this means you won't be able to change the value on-the-fly by editing postgresql.conf, so while the command-line method might be convenient, it can cost you flexibility later.

As far as I understand that doesn't change the `postgresql.conf` but it actually runs the `postgres` command with the desired options. That's probably why you don't see the value set to `all` in the configuration file.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to mount Postgres config file somewhere on the server and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I test your question in my pc.
In the `postgresql.conf` `log_statement="none"` is commented. 
Go manually and discomment it and it solve your problems.

`docker exec -it postgres bash`

Into the container:

- `apt update`
- `apt install vim`
- `vim /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf`
- search what do you are looking for and change it manually.
- Stop/start the container.

That is my solution.

Comment: This requires manual intervention every time the container is restarted.

Comment: No, with one time is enough, ensure you test the solutions before comment.